# Operate on all hidden slides in powerpoint

Tags: selections, microsoft-powerpoint

Hi I have a large number of hidden slides in my powerpoint presentation.
They are not contiguous, so that I can't select them using just the SHIFT key.    I'd like to color them with the same background color in one operation.      Is there a way of selecting all of my hidden slides and then operating on them?  Even better, but I imagine this is too much to ask, to set things up so that when I "hide" a slide, the background changes automatically

Answer (score 1):

Select them using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key instead, then apply a background color.

Holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key enables you to select / unselect individual slides.

For automatically changing the background color is probably necessary to write some code in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of "write some code in VBA", thank you @MarianD:

This will change the background color of each hidden slide to red: RGB(255,0,0)
You can modify that to any RGB value you like.

```
Sub SelectHiddenSlides()
    Dim oSl As Slide
    
    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        If oSl.SlideShowTransition.Hidden Then
            oSl.FollowMasterBackground = False
            oSl.Background.Fill.Solid
            oSl.Background.Fill.Visible = True
            oSl.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```